# RPC security of bitcoind node

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, wallet-security

If I have a fairly default `bitcoin.conf` file, let's say:

```
rpcport=8332
txconfirmtarget=6
```

ie: notably one where I don't specify things like `rpcuser`, `rpcpassword` - is this insecure?

As I understand, this lets the node be queried locally without an authentication. However I'm not sure this is any more dangerous than `wallet.dat` sitting around - local access would mean private key access.

Are default settings of bitcoin insecure?

Answer (score 2):

> ie: notably one where I don't specify things like rpcuser, rpcpassword - is this insecure?

No, Bitcoin Core by default creates a RPC cookie file in the data directory on startup which is used in place of static authentication. Specifying a `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` is deprecated, and they can't be blank regardless.

Comment: Gotcha. What's the name of that file by default? Not seeing it on disk nor in the documentation.

Comment: The name of the file is ".cookie", in the usual Bitcoin Core data directory.